# Does anyone can tell me how this custom javascript function to execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click 'cancel button' , I do not get the return $.Deferred object.
I am confused about this. what I think after click "cancel button" , I will get the $.Deferred object and $.Deferred

// javascript code

```
var str_confirmDialog = [
'<div class="tanChuang3" style="display: block;">',
'<div class="oh pa table">',
    '<div class="table-cell">',
        '<div class="bg-fff pr">',
            '<p class="tl"><strong>{title}</strong></p>',
            '<p class="tableCellTxt">{msg}</p>',
            '<p class="tr">',
                '<a href="javascript:;" class="_cancel">cancel</a>',
                '<a href="javascript:;" id="close" class="_next">OK</a>',
            '</p>',
        '</div>',
    '</div>',
    '<i class="close pa c-close-btn"></i>',
'</div>',
'<div class="tanChuangBg"></div>',
'</div>'].join('');
Hnb.ui = {

showConfirm: function(title , msg , sleep) {
            var defer = $.Deferred();
            var str_message = str_confirmDialog.replace('{title}' , title);
            var str_message = str_message.replace('{msg}' , msg);
            var $box = $(str_message).appendTo("body");

            $box.find(".c-close-btn").click(function() {
                $(this).unbind('click');
                $box.remove();
                defer.resolve();
            });

            // cancel button
            $box.find("._cancel").click(function(){
                $(this).unbind("click");
                $box.remove();
                // //If I do not comment this paragraph, it will be fine to execute always.
                //return defer.reject();
            }); 
            // next button
            $box.find("._next").click(function() {
                $(this).unbind("click");
                $box.remove();
                defer.resolve();
            });

            if(sleep) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $box.find('.c-close-btn').trigger('click');
                } , sleep);
            }
            return defer;
        }
}
```

// function called , after click cancel button , I do not get the $.Deferred object.

```
Hnb.ui.showConfirm('title' , 'msg' , 3000).done(function(){
   alert('done');
}).always(function() {
   alert('always');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reject the promise when cancel is clicked, you don't **return**, you just call `reject` (just like all the other click handlers just *call* `reject` or `resolve`):

```
// cancel button
$box.find("._cancel").click(function(){
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $box.remove();
    defer.reject(); // <== No return
});
```

Also note that when calling it, you're telling it to auto-confirm after three seconds:

```
Hnb.ui.showConfirm('title', 'msg', 3000)
// Here ---------------------------^
```

Here's a live example where I've done the `defer.reject()` above and commented-out the auto-close; works just fine:

```js
var Hnb = {}; // Added
var str_confirmDialog = [
  '<div class="tanChuang3" style="display: block;">',
  '<div class="oh pa table">',
  '<div class="table-cell">',
  '<div class="bg-fff pr">',
  '<p class="tl"><strong>{title}</strong></p>',
  '<p class="tableCellTxt">{msg}</p>',
  '<p class="tr">',
  '<a href="javascript:;" class="_cancel">cancel</a>',
  '<a href="javascript:;" id="close" class="_next">OK</a>',
  '</p>',
  '</div>',
  '</div>',
  '<i class="close pa c-close-btn"></i>',
  '</div>',
  '<div class="tanChuangBg"></div>',
  '</div>'
].join('');
Hnb.ui = {

  showConfirm: function(title, msg, sleep) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var str_message = str_confirmDialog.replace('{title}', title);
    var str_message = str_message.replace('{msg}', msg);
    var $box = $(str_message).appendTo("body");

    $box.find(".c-close-btn").click(function() {
      $(this).unbind('click');
      $box.remove();
      defer.resolve();
    });

    // cancel button
    $box.find("._cancel").click(function() {
      $(this).unbind("click");
      $box.remove();
      defer.reject();
    });
    // next button
    $box.find("._next").click(function() {
      $(this).unbind("click");
      $box.remove();
      defer.resolve();
    });

    if (sleep) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $box.find('.c-close-btn').trigger('click');
      }, sleep);
    }
    return defer;
  }
};

Hnb.ui.showConfirm('title', 'msg'/*, 3000*/).done(function() {
  $('<p>').text('done').appendTo(document.body);
}).always(function() {
  $('<p>').text('always').appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: You shouldn't return the `Deferred` object from `showConfirm`; you should return its *promise*:

```
return defer.promise();
```

That way, only your code can resolve or reject it. If you return the `Deferred`, the code you're passing it back to could also resolve or reject it.

Comment: It does not work. It seems after $box.remove() codes are not be executed.

Comment: @user39291: Yes, it does work. I've added a live example.

Comment: I have a quetion, if I do not defer.reject(), but I can not execute to always(). According to jQuery document, always will be executed whatever reject(), resolve, pending.

Comment: @user39291: *"According to jQuery document, always will be executed whatever reject(), resolve, pending"* Not *pending*, no. Just resolve or reject. It's : `done` - called only when resolved. `fail` - called only when rejected. `always` - always called. There's also `then` which accepts **three** callbacks (resolved, rejected, progress).